# Placing an image watermark

Tags: php, image-processing

I have this code for watermarking text onto an image

```
if($type==".jpg" or $type==".jpeg"){
  $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploaddir.$randnum);
}elseif($type==".gif"){
  $im = imagecreatefromgif($uploaddir.$randnum);   
}else{
  $im = imagecreatefrompng($uploaddir.$randnum); 
}

$imagesize = getimagesize($uploaddir.$randnum);

$x_offset = 7;
$y_offset = 8;

$textcolor  = imagecolorallocate($im, 0xCC, 0xCC, 0xCC);
$textcolor2 = imagecolorallocate($im, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
imagestring($im, 5, $x_offset, $y_offset, strtoupper($_POST['code']), $textcolor2);
if($type==".jpg" or $type==".jpeg"){
  imagejpeg($im,$uploaddir.$randnum,100);
}elseif($type==".gif"){
  imagegif($im,$uploaddir.$randnum,100);   
}else{
  imagepng($im,$uploaddir.$randnum,8);    
}
```

The code above is printing the watermark in the top left... But I want it to be written on the bottom in the right.

any help guys

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this where you're currently using `imagestring()`.

```
$font_size = 5;
$margin = 7;
$text_width = imagefontwidth($font_size)*strlen($_POST['code']);
$text_height = imagefontheight($font_size); //assuming it's one line
imagestring($im, $font_size, $imagesize[0] - $text_width - $margin, $imagesize[1] - $text_height - $margin, strtoupper($_POST['code']), $textcolor2);
```

Change `$margin` and `$font_size` to meet your needs.

Answer (score 2):

This is the line that actually places the watermark:

```
imagestring($im, 5, $x_offset, $y_offset, strtoupper($_POST['code']), $textcolor2);
```

The horizontal position of the watermark will depend on what you set `$x_offset` to be. Right now it's 7, which means 7 pixels from the left.

To get it to be 7 pixels form the right, set it to be the width of the whole image, minus (7 + the width of the watermark)

Find the width of the watermark with [imagettfbbox](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php).

The principles are the same for setting the vertical position.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move it to the bottom, just change your y offset to be the bottom of the image, instead of '8' (which is probably near the top):

```
$y_offset = $imagesize['height'] - 7;
```

Comment: what happened when you did that? How tall is the watermark?  It needs to be the size of the image minus the size of the watermark.  I'm just guessing the watermark has a height of '7'.